# bind keyup.enter with tab using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

do someone knows how i can bind the keyup.enter proproty to the tab of the keyboard?
i mean i want that when i enter the value in a first field of my form that i spring in the second field.
Like:

```
<form>
<label for="xxx">first:
 <input type="text" id="first" name="first" (keyup.enter)="enterFirst(firstName)">
</label>
<label for="xxx">second:
 <input type="text" id="second" name="second" (keyup.enter)="enterSecond(lastName)">
</label>
.
.
.
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="sendNames(xxx)">valid</button>
</form>
```

So i would to be able to spring on the field second when i give the firstname and click on enter.

Do someone have an idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it is vanilla JS:

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="first" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == '13') {enterFirst(this)}">
```

(EDITED: Replaced "firstName" with "this")

Comment: first thank you for your answer @Lemindoge. but when i have this error on the console       (index):14 Uncaught ReferenceError: enterFirst is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup ((index):14)

Comment: Oh, replace "firstName" with "this". If that doesn't work, I think "enterFirst" probably doesn't exist in your code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
   <h1>Here we will try to bind  the keyup.enter with Tab</h1>
   <div class="container">
   
     <h2>Please enter datas an click on enter</h2>
     <form>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col">
           <label for="fname">Enter your firstname:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter your firstname and click enter"
         id="fname" name="fname" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == '13') {enterFirst(this)}">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col">
           <label for="lname">Enter your lastname:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter your lastname and click enter"
         id="lname" name="lname" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode == '13') {enterLast(this)}">
         </div>
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="sendData()">submit</button>
     </form>
   
   </div>
```

Ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angulartest';
  public firstname: string;

  constructor(){}

  ngOninit(){

  }

  enterFirst(firstname){
    console.log(firstname);
  }

  sendData(){

  }
}
```

I wrote it just to see if i can spring to the field lastname by clicking on enter after the firstname